# Search results on Area51 should suggest creating a new proposal

Tags: discussion, feature-request

If no search results are returned by a search on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the results page has the following suggestions:

- Make sure all words are spelled correctly
- Use different words
- Use more general words

Shouldn't it also suggest "Create a Proposal" and give instructions for how to do so?

Also, in several places the FAQ tells you to propose new sites. Ex:

> If your area of expertise doesn't already have a Stack Exchange site, propose it!

However, in no case does it ever *actually tell you the steps you need to follow to do it* (i.e. select a category, scroll down and click "Propose a new X site")

I only found this information in two places:

1. My list of [Privileges](http://area51.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-proposals)
2. At the very bottom of the homepage, where it says

> Can't find what you're looking for?
>   Select a category listing to the left and propose your site there!

Shouldn't it be in the FAQ as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proposal means a big engagement from the proposer and the commiters. And the process is long (I know it : [the proposal I support](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12692/stack-overflow-in-french?referrer=adVDNkMqm5jZeiYutxUqXw2) is at the same number of commiters it was a few weeks ago even while I mention it as soon as I find a pretext).

That's not something you do just because your search didn't return a result.

So I don't think the proposal creation should be recommended in the search result. If you think you should propose something, you start by reading the FAQ and looking at what exists and how other proposals are doing.